# Connect to SQL Server 2008 Express using php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-express

How can I connect to SQL Server 2008 Express?
I'm able to connect to SQL Server 2008 with PHP, but not to the previous version.

Comment: You really need to give us more to work with here.  For example.  What connection strings are you using.  What error message are you getting.  What php version.  Are you using PEAR or another method to connect?  This question doesn't provide enough context to allow anyone to help you.

Comment: What data access layer are you using? PDO or MSSQL?